# about cudaMemcpy() function about whether both the source and destination pointers can be null

Tags: cuda

In `cudaMemcpy()`, can the both source and destination pointers be null? I am a beginner in CUDA. so please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes i have tried...actually i am facing another problem...and i am trying to make sure that it is not the cause...

Answer (score 5):

It is not valid to do so.

The pointers passed to `cudaMemcpy` should be properly allocated pointers.  NULL is not a properly allocated pointer.

If you do [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api), I think the API will return an error (invalid parameter) with NULL pointers when it is expecting a proper device pointer.